# how use caching in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I have problem with cache in my asp.net mvc3 application.

**My code**

```
using System.Web.Caching;
...
class RegularCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
    Cache cache ;

    public object Get(string name)
    {
        return cache[name];
    }

    public void Set(string name, object value)
    {
        cache.Insert(name, value);
    }

    public void Unset(string name)
    {
        cache.Remove(name);
    }
}
```

And I use singleton for give value for it :

```
School schoolSettings = (School)CacheProviderFactory.Cache.Get("SchoolSettings");
            if (schoolSettings == null)
            {
                CacheProviderFactory.Cache.Set("SchoolSettings", someObject);
            }
```

So in first use it does not work and give me an error `cache[name]` is null.

What I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check out output caching for MVC3? BTW Siema!

Comment: Witam :) I need use Cache this way.

Comment: Were you planning on assigning a value to `cache` at some point? 'cos you haven't.

Comment: Also, you claim `cache` is a singleton and that there is a `CacheProviderFactory.Cache` - neither of these things are shown in the code. You are asking us to guess what you have removed; that will not lead to a good answer...

Comment: Slightly off topic but you might want to look at using dependency injection to provide the cache instance. That way you can change it to another caching provider if needed and you can also unit test easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the HttpRuntime.Cache, this example would cache for an hour?

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("SchoolSettings", someObject, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                       System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                       System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
```

Comment: I need to use `System.Web.Caching`

Comment: @MateuszRogulski why is that? this is a private implementation detail; frankly it shouldn't *matter* how it is implemented

Comment: Well, I have change it with your method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

At no point have you given `cache` a value... and note that the *regular* web cache probably isn't your best bet if you want it separate; perhaps

```
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache();
```

Comment: I have had the same problem - problem with null reference. But I have change it for `HttpRuntime.Cache`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. it works fine for my project

```
 using System.Runtime.Caching;

    public class RegularCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
        {
            private ObjectCache Cache { get { return MemoryCache.Default; } }

            object ICacheProvider.Get(string key)
            {
                return Cache[key];
            }

            void ICacheProvider.Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime = 30)
            {
                var policy = new CacheItemPolicy {AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime)};
                Cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
            }

            void ICacheProvider.Unset(string key)
            {
                Cache.Remove(key);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code where you check for the value as follow:

> School schoolSettings = CacheProviderFactory.Cache.Get("SchoolSettings") as (School);

Notice that I am using "as" rather than casting the object. Cast will blow up if the value is null while "as" will just give you a null value which is what you expect.

Comment: Like Marc Gravel mentioned, Are you sure cache is not null by the time the Get method is called?